# Rails nested forms link_to_add new entry placement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form where the link_to_add appears only by the side of the last entry, meanwhile the previous entries all have only the link_to_remove.

What I need is for it to be possible to:
1- remove the last entry in the form, currently the link_to_remove does not appear for the last entry.
2- add a new entry between two existing ones, example: if there are 2 entries, 1 and 2, I can only append a new entry after 2, I can't add a new entry between 1 and 2.

This is the code for the partial where one of theses nested forms is generated:

```
<div id="perguntas">
  <%= f.fields_for :perguntas do |m| %>
      <div class="field plus-field">
        <%= m.input :pergunta , :label=> false , :placeholder => "Escreva uma pergunta" %>
      </div>
      <%= m.link_to_remove "-",:class => "link-add-field" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="adiciona-botao-field ">
  <div class="field plus-field">
  </div>
  <%= f.link_to_add "+", :perguntas, :class => "link-add-field", 'data-target' => '#perguntas' %>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to check `http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1` and `http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2`

Comment: I had checked them before, but it seems to use a simple way to add questions at the bottom and does not care about the new entry placement